# Where to put higher resolution images?

Tags: android

I am designing app for both mobiles and tab versions.

I read that for tabs, we need higher resolution images and these must be put in **res folder** of our project.

But where to put these images? in which drawable folder of **res**?

Here i can find following folders in res folder.

1. drawable-hdpi
2. drawable-ldpi
3. drawable-mdpi
4. drawable-xhdpi
5. drawable-xxhdpi

I placed all my images for normal mobile screens such as **Nexus one** in **drawable-hdpi**. My question is, now where should i place my higher resolution images?

Help please, Thankyou

Comment: please reffere my recent answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773858/bitmap-size-appears-different-in-different-android-device/23773898#23773898

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android you have the option hdpi, mdpi, xdpi,etc..

folders for that , you have to create different images according your device resolution and put your images at there after confirming your device resolution and density category.

for the more reference why it'll happen you can see here

here i explain some chart may be helpful to you.

```
Low density Small screens QVGA 240x320 (120dpi):

layout-small-ldpi (240x320)  
layout-small-land-ldpi (320x240)

Low density Normal screens WVGA400 240x400 (x432) (120dpi):

layout-ldpi  (240 x 400 )
layout-land-ldpi  (400 x 240 )

Medium density Normal screens HVGA 320x480 (160dpi):

layout-mdpi (320 x 480 )
layout-land-mdpi (480 x 320 )

Medium density Large screens HVGA 320x480 (160dpi):

layout-large-mdpi (320 x 480 )
layout-large-land-mdpi (480 x 320)

Galaxy Tab ( 240 dpi ):

layout-large  (600 x 1024) 
layout-large-land  (1024 x 600)

High density Normal screens WVGA800 480x800 (x854) (240 dpi):

layout-hdpi (480 x 800)
layout-land-hdpi (800 x 480)

Xoom (medium density large but 1280x800 res) (160 dpi):

layout-xlarge (800 x 1280)
layout-xlarge-land (1280 x 800)
```

Comment: yeah. got you, but my screen resolution is 3.7" WVGA 480x800: hdpi and now iam doing for 7.3" 800x1280 :tvdpi So where shall i place my big images for 7.3" screen resolution?

Comment: For that you need to create this folder and put your image in it.
`res/drawable-sw720dp
res/drawable-sw800dp 
/res/drawable-tvdpi`

Comment: obviously, in `/res/drawable-tvdpi`

Comment: yes, i created res/drawable-tvdpi and placed my images. Just got it. Thank you :) its working

Comment: Stongly Welcome @Sravani